# How to change the color of text inside equation environments in Kile?

Tags: equations, kile

The default color of fonts and symbols inside the equation environments in **Kile** is pale green, which is not very pleasant to my eyes... Is there an easy way to change this?

Comment: change it in the setup for the editor, available via the menu bar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the main menu of Kile, choose **Settings** and then **Configure Kile**. A window opens, in the left navigation tree choose **Editor**, **Fonts & Colors**. Then, on the right, click **Highlighting Text Styles**. Look for **Math** and change the green color to another one. Just double click on the green area next to **Math** and choose the color in the following color dialog.

[image]